# How to create effect: light button when mouse over button in C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created an app by C# Winform, similar : Window Media Player. When mouse over button, I don't know what for creating light button as in app Media Media Player.

[image]

Comment: It all depends on how did you made your code/design. It can be made by custom draw, or by replacing images. Show us your code. But my recommendation is, do not use such a effect and custom designs. Use it only when it is absolutely necessary. When the application is for your own use, bear without fancy design. When the application is meant for publishing, you need to handle too many cases *(e.g. different displaying DPI, different colour schemes, and many other problems)*. It is simple too much work for a simple fancy feature.

Comment: To achieve similar smooth highlight effect in Windows Media Player buttons, you need to use WPF. Because Windows Media Player v11 or later is using WPF. Using image switch in Windows Forms is not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two images. One for normal button, one image for hovered button state.
Drag button control from toolbox, make *FlatStyle* to *Popup*.

Create *button.MouseEnter* and *button.MouseLeave* event.

```
// Let's say you have images stores in resource file..
private static readonly Image image1 = Resources.button1;
private static readonly Image image2 = Resources.button2;
...
button1.MouseEnter += (s,e) => button1.Image = image2;
// And revert back
button1.MouseLeave += (s,e) => button1.Image = image1;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Thompson very much :)

Answer (score 1):

On the button's Mouse_Enter event change the buttons background image, then changee it back on Mouse_Leave.

```
private Image cachedImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\mouseOver.jpg");
```

...

```
button1.BackgroundImage = cachedImage;
```